# Simple foreach loop in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

```
   <% foreach (var car in Model.AvailableCars)
  { %>
       <label><%car.Text; %></label>

   <% } %>
```

The above code throws the error

***Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.***

I know I can do it with html helpers, but why won't the above code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<label><%car.Text; %></label>
```

should read

```
<label><%= car.Text; %></label>  
         ^
```

or you can use

```
<label><%: car.Text; %></label>
         ^
```

which will automatically `HTML.Encode` the value for you.

Comment: That worked:). I will accept this as the answer as soon as it lets me (in 9 mins)

Comment: Unless you have an explicit reason to NOT HtmlEncode the value being displayed I'd recommend always using `<%:car.Text%>` to write your text to the page. Or in the case of Razor, `@car.Text` which HtmlEncodes all text by default. You'd have to explicitly use `@Html.Raw(car.Text)` to not HtmlEncode it with Razor.

Answer (score 1):

Add a colon to the `car.Text` tag to write it to the document, such as:

```
<label><%: car.Text %></label>
```

Here's a good explanation of `<%:` versus `<%=` [asp.net mvc tags: <%: %> vs. <%= %>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799112/asp-net-mvc-tags-vs)